# UI in JAVA Suggestion

Tags: java, graphics, user-interface, graph

I need your suggestion on this:

1. Suggest/Recommend a tool and/or version of Java to use for developing bar graphs by reading input from text file.
2. I am working on a group project and my friend will provide the data (internet usage, time duration and name of application in form of numbers) I need to show this in form of UI, I want this Java code to run as a exe, which on clicking reads file (text preferably) stored in local machine and show user the analysis graph.

Comment: why would someone mark it -1.? Its a valid question buddy..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to basically do the following

1. Write a java program to read the file content to a data model. Depending on the file format, you can find open source parsers.
2. Once you read the data, you can use a library like JFreechart to create a bar chart and display to the user. for more info look here [enter link description here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)
3. There are lots of libraries to make a java application as an executable. one such library is [enter link description here](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)